# Android:How to Update a local XML file when device finds internet connectivity

Tags: android, xml

I am developing an Android application. This application has XML file locally stored within the application apk file. This file contains data to be displayed in the application. I have a latest  updated xml file on the server. Now I want to update this file on the device either in background or by notifying user. whenever device finds internet connectivity,it should check the file modification date and should update/replace an old file with the new file from the server.

Comment: Unless it is  a SharedPreferences file or just external xml data file , the files living under /res/layout , can not be changed in your program.

Comment: @AIL It is an external file in assets folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check Internet availability with this code:

```
public boolean isConnectivityOn(Context ctx) {
    boolean resCode = false;

    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        resCode = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }

    return resCode;
}
```

Having in the Manifest the following Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and calling the above method:

```
if (isConnectivityOn()) {
    //update XML
} else { 
    //don't update XML
}
```

Comment: May I know how can I check date modified of the xml file in assets folder, because I don't want to update the file if both the files are same